# Unable to change font color

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbGreen  ' Working Fine

Range("A5").Font.Color = vbRed ' Not working Getting no error
```

Comment: `Interior` or `Font`? No repro.

Comment: Use the macro recorder. Look at the code it generates. Viola.

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps you have some conditional formatting active on that cell?

Comment: No conditional formatting active as cell color changed to red when used interior.color.